# Install TensorFlow's tf-nightly and tf-nightly-gpu on macOS

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have run into a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14182) with TensorFlow 1.4 and Python 3.6, which manifests itself by this `RuntimeWarning`:

```
compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' 
does not match runtime version 3.6
```

I would like to overcome by installing the latest `tf-nightly` and `tf-nightly-gpu`, as currently recommended. So far, I have so far followed [normal instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) for installing TensorFlow (on macOS) like so:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
(tensorflow)$ easy_install -U pip
(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

What (minimal) changes to these steps so that they perform installation from `tf-nightly` and `tf-nightly-gpu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using command `pip install tf-nightly` instead of `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` seems to work. It currently leads to installation from `tf_nightly-1.5.0.dev20171206-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl`.

Answer (score 0):

using `--upgrade` will try to get tensorflow for the python version it was originally installed for, which the error says is 3.5, while you're currently apparently running 3.6 as the default

Comment: So what's the solution in your opinion?